# MVC split form over several views

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Can I call the same action from a controller then move on to the next view. So that when users completing a record on a mobile do so over several pages(or views). For instance:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("CompleteJob", "Job", new { Model.ID })" data-role="submit">Start Job</a>
```

I want to link to as well view aswell as controller. I have created a StartJob.cshtml view but I am not sure how I can direct to that particular view and specific form input from the controller?Tried something like this:

```
public ActionResult CompleteJob(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Job Job1 = db.Jobs.Find(id);
        if (Job1== null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(Job1);
    }
```

Obviously I can use @Html.ActionLink because I want to embed within Jquery Mobile buttons

Comment: are all the views in same controller?

Comment: They are yep. Job1, Job2, Job3.  Should be return View(Job) above

Comment: I cant work out how to return both the data, and correct view from @Url.Action

Comment: Thats the problem, It doesn't work. Do I have to give the action the same name as the view?

Comment: Yep. But from <a href="@Url.Action("StartJob", new { Model.ID })" data-role="button">Start Job</a> I can only specify the action. How do I return the correct view.

Comment: Ok but that will not return the model data relevant to the ID, just the view?

Comment: then try return View("Job1",Job1)

Comment: first parameter is your view name,and second is your model data

Comment: Heh. Thanks! Working as expected now. Did you want to update answer and I will mark as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button role should be submit also like below

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Start","Job" new { Model.ID })" data-role="submit">Start Job</a>
```

In your your view

if you want to return job1 view then use

```
return View("YourVIewName",modelDataYouWantToPass);
```

Comment: Without simple matching the action to the view name

Comment: Ok so. Controller is called job. Action is called complete job and first view is called Job1. Your method links to /Job/CompleteJob/2 which is incorrect.